# Postscript file will not open image

Tags: ghostscript, postscript, adobe-illustrator

I have a .PS file that I would like to view, but am not able to even through countless trial and errors.

Please download the file here https://www.dropbox.com/s/ehnmib05wdhspfc/acsii_kfsh_logo.ps?dl=0

An error that comes up is:

```
 %%[ Error: nocurrentpoint; OffendingCommand: currentpoint ]%%
 %%[ Flushing: rest of job (to end-of-file) will be ignored ]%%
 %%[ Warning: PostScript error. No PDF file produced. ] %%
```

From my understanding, that means that there was a problem with the way PostScript code was generated. Teh file was sent to me to view the image, but I am not able to view it. Could it be that the error is coming up because it was incorrectly generated? The sender says it is working just fine with them, and that is what really frustrates me because it's not working with me.

Any help will be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is *something* wrong in your workflow, but it's hard to spot what. "The sender says it is working just fine with them" doesn't really mean anything -- what specific software are they using? And since this is clearly an *export* and not an original file, is it *this* file that "works for them" or do they mean the *original* does?

Anyway, the file contains two errors:

1. Instead of the usual slash for `/name` notation, this file contains tildes `~`:

   ```
   currentpoint ~y$pos exch def ~x$pos exch def
   ```

   That is a weird error because it is **invalid PostScript**, and no regular software can be expected to work with this. This is the cause of the following error that I get:

   ```
   %%[ Error: undefined; OffendingCommand: ~y$pos ]%%
   ```

   Somehow you don't see this error, so there must be something else wrong! Perhaps the file was damaged in transferring to your Dropbox (which would be an achievement on its own).

   Should it also be on your side: to fix, replace each occurrence of the `~` character with `/`.
2. The file starts with defining *x* and *y* coordinates, based on the *current* point. But this needs additional information: the actual drawing coordinate is not given, and so it must rely on other software to provide the drawing coordinate. Of course neither Adobe Illustrator nor Distiller do this -- they assume the file is self-contained, a reasonable assumption.

This causes the error message

```
    %%[ Error: nocurrentpoint; OffendingCommand: currentpoint ]%%
```

To fix it you can add the following line at the top:

```
    0 0 moveto
```

and it will distill properly.

Proper software such as InDesign and Illustrator will still be unable to open the file as image, because it's missing something else: a proper header. The very minimum needed is this, at the very top of the file:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 92 87
```

---

After all this work I found the file doesn't contain any vector information at all! EPS is quite a bad choice to send out bitmaps; TIFF is the industry standard for these, but a PNG or even a lowly BMP file would have done, and then without all of the problems you encountered. Discuss this with your supplier.

Comment: You truly are a lifesaver! I am able to view the image now (but it is tiny for some odd reason, no worries). So sorry for the lack of details in my original question -- honestly thank you so much!